# Aspect from the dependency spring boot jar file is not working

Tags: spring, spring-boot, aspectj, spring-aop

I have 1 spring boot project which defines the Aspect to be called if exception is thrown. I have another spring boot project where that Aspect should be applied. But it seems that aspect is not working when exception is thrown.
Git repository link: https://github.com/ketss/Spring-Boot-Aspect
2 projects on 2 different branches.
master1: Dependency spring boot project which contains Aspect
master2: Main application 
Can someone tell me what exactly am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to annotate your ExceptionProcessorAspect class with @Configuration.

I believe you should paste @Configuration above @Aspect Annotation.

Comment: You mean "@Component" instead of "@Configuration"

Comment: @Kets P: I mean "@Configuration" should be applied as long an you Annotate bean with "@Aspect" considering you are relying on java Configuration.

Comment: @RahulGupta, I have another class named AspectConfiguration where "@Configuration" is applied and which returns the Aspect Bean. Is it still required to add "@Configuration" to Aspect?

Comment: @kets did you find a solution?